# Plotting distribution of training data

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-os

I am trying to plot my label data as a histogram. I have data in .txt file example is below.

```
78/1/2014/3ac218c0c6c378.jpg
78/1/2010/588feea1fcc809.jpg
78/1/2010/071c428717ceca.jpg
78/1/2010/4c119af3fdb787.jpg
78/1/2014/1453dbb876c191.jpg
78/1/2013/5a9cb4ee24047d.jpg
78/1/2012/106f7ea2150ff7.jpg
78/1/2012/6481ae22830294.jpg
78/1/2013/23bc02fcf393f8.jpg
78/1/2014/84919e1b067a85.jpg
78/1/2013/603cd9ca33d572.jpg
78/1/2012/f5a52935ee6fc2.jpg
78/1/2012/80e52b10388f9e.jpg
```

Now in this 78 folder I have total of more than 1000 pictures but in train.txt I am using 13. How can I plot the distribution of train.txt and actual data.

What I tried to do is till now is below

**CODE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
train = open("D:/compCarsThesisData/data/train_test_split/classification/train.txt", "r")
path = "D:/compCarsThesisData/data/image/78/"

for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        cdp = os.path.abspath(root)
        for f in files:
            name,ext = os.path.splitext(f)
            if ext == ".jpg":
               for x in train:
                   plt.hist(int(x.rsplit('/')[0]), int(path.rsplit('/')[4]))
plt.show()
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you,